# function not returning value in object oriented php structure

Tags: php, function, oop, inheritance

I am very new to Object oriented PHP and i am learning through some basic examples. I have index.php file in which i have created class and used getters and setters. And in class_lib.php file i have created object of the class and try to echoing the value. But i am not getting any value returned.

inde.php

```
<?php
class person {
var $name;

 function __construct($persons_name) 
 {
        $this->name = $persons_name;
 }

 function set_name($new_name) 
 {
        $this->name = $new_name;
 }

 function get_name() 
 {
        return $this->name;
 } 
}

class employee extends person
{
    function __construct($employee_name)
    {
        $this->set_name($employee_name);
    }
}
?>
```

class_lib.php

```
<?php
include "index.php";

$stefan = new person("Stefan Mischook");
echo "Stefan's full name: " . $stefan->get_name();
echo '<br>';
$james = new employee("Johnny Fingers");
echo "new employee---> " . $james->get_name();
?>
```

Comment: Your code works: http://ideone.com/4ZUYQP

Comment: Are you sure your include path is correct ? This code works well

Comment: did u make any changes ? Because its not running for me ...

Comment: try to var_dump($stefan); var_dump($james) and see and tell us what's inside.

Comment: @user3844830 "not running" is too unsepcific for us to really help. Enable error reporting and you'll most likely already see what is going wrong

Comment: @user3844830: I copied your code and inserted to ideone. You could try it yourself instead of asking.

Comment: yes my include path is correct till now its running fine but i dont know its not running now when i make changes in my code

Comment: error reporting now showing any errors

Comment: plz remove negative voting as i did not know why the error has occured..and i have mentioned in my question i am new to OOP PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change class_lib.php code to index.php code and index.php code to class_lib.php

index.php

```
<?php
    include "class_lib.php";
    $stefan = new person("Stefan Mischook");
    echo "Stefan's full name: " . $stefan->get_name();
    echo '<br>';
    $james = new employee("Johnny Fingers");
    echo "new employee---> " . $james->get_name();
?>
```

class_lib.php

```
<?php
    class person {
    var $name;
    function __construct($persons_name) 
    {
        $this->name = $persons_name;
    }
    function set_name($new_name) 
    {
        $this->name = $new_name;
    }
    function get_name()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
    }
    class employee extends person
    {
    function __construct($employee_name)
    {
        $this->set_name($employee_name);
    }
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: i tried but still now running i am getting output as :          Stefan's full name:
new employee--->

Comment: Till now i ran few basic examples of oop it runs perfectly

Comment: you should put 'private' instead 'var', var was used long time ago in php history ;), private couse you should hide access to datafields of your class

Comment: i think you opened index.php instead of class_lib.php.

According to your code index.php will be displaying blank and class_lib.php will display the name.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code executed on PHP 5.4.4: http://ideone.com/KvrQVF

output:

```
Stefan's full name: Stefan Mischook
new employee---> Johnny Fingers
```

It seems to be working properly.